# Resolving p2 dependencies in an Eclipse product

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, p2

I am trying to install a feature (`com.iar.cdt.arm.sdk.feature`) in an Eclipse product (`MCUXpressoIDE`).
The feature has a requirement on another feature (`org.eclipse.emf.feature`, with no version specified) which is part of the product itself (in version 2.19, as `org.eclipse.emf.common.feature`). Despite this, p2 is trying to fetch the same feature from one of the available update sites, resulting in a conflict and installation error.

Does p2 consider the product itself as a source for needed features, in addition to the update sites? If not, why?

EDIT: It does, see the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63830538/885586)

The original installation exception follows:

```
 Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
 Software being installed: IAR Toolchain for ARM (8.30.x - 8.50.x) 8.1.0.202007252323 (com.iar.cdt.arm.sdk.feature.feature.group 8.1.0.202007252323)
 Software currently installed: MCUXpresso IDE 11.2.0.202007071544 (MCUXpressoIDE 11.2.0.202007071544)
 Only one of the following can be installed at once:
 EMF Common 2.17.0.v20190920-0401 (org.eclipse.emf.common.feature.jar 2.17.0.v20190920-0401)
 EMF Common 2.19.0.v20200324-0932 (org.eclipse.emf.common.feature.jar 2.19.0.v20200324-0932)
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
 From: MCUXpresso IDE 11.2.0.202007071544 (MCUXpressoIDE 11.2.0.202007071544)
 To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.emf.common.feature.group [2.19.0.v20200324-0932,2.19.0.v20200324-0932]
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
 From: IAR Toolchain for ARM (8.30.x - 8.50.x) 8.1.0.202007252323 (com.iar.cdt.arm.sdk.feature.feature.group 8.1.0.202007252323)
 To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.emf.feature.group 0.0.0
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
 From: EMF Common 2.17.0.v20190920-0401 (org.eclipse.emf.common.feature.group 2.17.0.v20190920-0401)
 To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.emf.common.feature.jar [2.17.0.v20190920-0401,2.17.0.v20190920-0401]
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
 From: EMF Common 2.19.0.v20200324-0932 (org.eclipse.emf.common.feature.group 2.19.0.v20200324-0932)
 To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.emf.common.feature.jar [2.19.0.v20200324-0932,2.19.0.v20200324-0932]
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
 From: EMF - Eclipse Modeling Framework Runtime and Tools 2.20.0.v20191028-0905 (org.eclipse.emf.feature.group 2.20.0.v20191028-0905)
 To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.emf.common.feature.group [2.17.0.v20190920-0401,2.17.0.v20190920-0401]
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. As I understand it, the installation of _IAR Toolchain for ARM_ fails in the _MCUXpresso IDE_ product because _IAR Toolchain for ARM_ requires exactly version 2.17 of _EMF Common_ (it does not allow a version range as usual, e.g. 2.17 or higher, but less 3.0). And this fails because the product contains and requires  _EMF Common_ also in the exact version, but 2.19. If I understand it correctly, the product contains it via a non-`installMode="root"` feature, so downgrading _EMF Common_ does not work either.

Comment: The _IAR Toolchain for ARM_ has a requirement on EMF 2.6.1 or higher (no matching rule is specified): I am investigating if the lack of a matching rule might be the issue here.

The question is about why p2 attempts to install another EMF version coming from an update site (2.17) rather than using the one already installed in the product (2.19), despite not being any exact requirement on EMF 2.17 in the IAR feature.

Comment: I have now edited the question to correct the features and versions, so that they are as in the error message. I hadn't noticed that the EMF dependencies between the IAR and the MCUXpresso features use different features, which might explain why it fails.

Comment: I have to correct myself. _IAR Toolchain for ARM_ (`com.iar.cdt.arm.sdk.feature.feature.group`) requires _EMF_ (`org.eclipse.emf.feature.group`) of any version (`0.0.0`). The one available EMF (obviously not yet installed) on an update site is 2.20 which requires _EMF Common_ 2.17. Does adding the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/builds/release/2.22`](https://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/builds/release/2.22) fix it?

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks! The issue lies in the different feature dependencies between the product and the feature being installed. Adding the update site as you describes elegantly solves the issue. If you'd like to submit this as an aswer I will be glad to accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the installation exception, the ***IAR Toolchain for ARM*** (`com.iar.cdt.arm.sdk.feature.feature.group`) **requires EMF** (`org.eclipse.emf.feature.group`) of any version (`0.0.0`). The in the update sites **available *EMF* is 2.20** which comes **with *EMF Common* 2.17**. But this **conflicts** with ***EMF Common* 2.19** that is a fixed part of the ***MCUXpresso IDE*** product (`MCUXpressoIDE`).

To solve this conflict, make available ***EMF* 2.22** using ***EMF Common* 2.19** by adding the following update site:
[**`https://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/builds/release/2.22`**](https://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/builds/release/2.22)